# Regexp is not defined in Jest test

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, babeljs, jestjs

I have a module `./main.js` that I am trying to test using `./__tests__/main-test.js`. `./main.js` uses `new Regexp(REGEX, 'g')` in one of its exported functions.

Running `jest` produces this error:

**`ReferenceError: Regexp is not defined`**

I thought it may be a mocking problem and added `jest.unmock('Regexp')` to `main-test.js` (even though it's not a required module), but got the same result.

What isn't `Regexp` defined?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Cause it should be `RegExp` , case sensitive, remember? otherwise the interpreter is searching for an object called `Regexp` which is not the desired Reg**E**xp constructor.

Comment: Thank you! What is strange is that the code executes just fine when run without Jest. Do you know why it would be allowed to run case insensitive?

Comment: Cause **jest** is right there to test your code :) Otherwise looks like it silently fails considering it as some globally accessible function / object on parse time...